# Remove acroform in pdf

Tags: pdfbox

Im using [removeField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/RemoveField.java) to remove field of a document but how can I remove completly acroform in pdf?
Im aware of

> acroform.flatten()

But i wonder if this is the correct method to remove all acroform ? Is there better way of doing this making maybe pdf smaller in size? Or remove acroform faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(null)` and also remove all widget annotations from each page:

```
    List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
    List<PDAnnotation> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PDAnnotation ann : annotations)
    {
        if (!(ann instanceof PDAnnotationWidget))
        {
            newList.add(ann);
        }
    }
    if (newList.isEmpty())
    {
        page.setAnnotations(null);
    }
    else
    {
        page.setAnnotations(newList);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the list be `page.setAnnotations(newList);` instead?

Comment: @BkSantiago indeed! Thanks!